# Prove $\int_{a}^{b}(\int_{a}^{t_{1}}\cdots(\int_{a}^{t_{n-1}} f(\tau)d\tau)dt_{n-1}\cdots)dt_{1}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)(b-x)^{n-1}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For continuous function $f$ on $\left<a, b\right>$, prove that:

$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(
\int_{a}^{t_{1}} \cdots \left(
\int_{a}^{t_{n - 1}} f(\tau)d\tau\right)
dt_{n - 1} \cdots\right)
dt_{1} = \frac{1}{(n - 1)!}\int_{a}^{b}f(\tau)(b - \tau)^{n - 1}d\tau$$

As hint, I should prove it with induction with initial case $n = 2$ and use integration by parts on the right side.

I am struggling to prove it with intitial case. For n = 2 I got:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}\left(
\int_{a}^{x}
f(\tau)d\tau \right)dx 
=& \int_{a}^{b}f(\tau)(b - \tau)d\tau \\
\end{align}
$$

1. Using theorem: $$\int_{a}^{b}{g(x).h'(x)dx} = [g(x).h(x)]_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b}{g'(x).h(x)dx}$$
2. We have:
   $$g(\tau) = (b - \tau)$$
   $$g'(\tau) = -1$$
   $$h(\tau) = \int_{a}^{b}{f(\tau)}d\tau$$
   $$h'(\tau) = f(\tau)$$
3. By applying theorem we have:
   $$\begin{align}
   \int_{a}^{b}f(\tau)(b - \tau)d\tau 
   =& \left[(b - \tau)\int_{a}^{b}f(\tau) d\tau\right]_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b}{(-1).\left(\int_{a}^{b}{f(t) dt}\right) d\tau} \\
   =& \left[(b - \tau)\int_{a}^{b}f(\tau) d\tau\right]_{a}^{b} + \int_{a}^{b}{\left(\int_{a}^{b}{f(t) dt}\right) d\tau} \\
   =& \int_{a}^{b}{\left((b - \tau)f(\tau) - \left(\int_{a}^{b}{f(t) dt}\right)\right)d\tau} + \int_{a}^{b}{\left(\int_{a}^{b}{f(t) dt}\right) d\tau} \\
   =& \int_{a}^{b}f(\tau)(b - \tau)d\tau
   \end{align}
   $$

But can't prove it for left side.

Thanks.

[source](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ehalas/MA/MA1/kopacek_-_mat._analyza_nejen_pro_fyziky_1.pdf#page=177)

Comment: Second equality is wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks, found the error and updated question.

Comment: Your work in  the first line of $3$ is incorrect. You are not applying the integration by parts correctly.

Comment: @DionelJaime I think I get what you mean. Yes primitive function of $f(x)$ on <a, b> should be $\int_{a}^{x}{f(t)dt}$, got it probably wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written above:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(\tau)(b - \tau)d\tau 
= \left[(b - \tau)\int_{a}^{b}f(\tau) d\tau\right]_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b}{(-1).\left(\int_{a}^{b}{f(t) dt}\right) d\tau} $$

This is not correct. You've mistaken an antiderivative $f$, namely $F(x)$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ , with the definite integral $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx  $.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we know that $F'(x) = f(x)$ where  $F(x) = \int_a^x f(\tau) \ d \tau$. So we use your integration by parts formula:

\begin{align} 
\int_a^b f(x) (b-x)  \ dx & = \int_a^b F'(x) (b-x) \ dx \\
& = (b-x)F(x)\bigg|_{x = a}^{x = b} + \int_a^b F(x) \ dx \\
& = 0 + \int_a^b F(x) \ dx  \\
& = \int_a^b \int_a^x f(\tau) \ d \tau \ dx
\end{align}

I left out two small justifications that you should be able to fill in.